# java multithreading issue

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrent-programming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

I am writing a program to simulate the hare and turtle race!
I am using getName() to see which objects thread is executing and based on that i increment the objects value. This is my code:

```
public void run()
{
    try{
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)

    {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        if(Thread.currentThread().getName() == "HARE")
        {

            hare++;
            System.out.println("hare thread");
            Thread.sleep(100);
            if(hare ==  49) 
            {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }   
        }
        if(Thread.currentThread().getName() == "TURTLE")
        {
            turtle++;
            Thread.sleep(250);  
        System.out.println("Turtle Thread");

        }
```

The problem is that even thought it detects the name of the thread accurately but it never goes inside the if block.
P.S I am new to java multithreading.
Thank you for going through the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Thread.currentThread().getName() == "HARE"
```

you can not compare string in this way.

```
Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("HARE");
```

the `equals` method is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.eqauls()` instead of `==` while comparing strings/objects.

So, your code should be something like below:

```
Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("HARE")
```

`==` compares for reference equality, that means both references point to same object or not. `equals()` method does content eqaulity, in other words checks Strings are same or not (Which is the one you required).